# How to change result set view format in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to change My result set in sql server 2012

My Result set is

```
Name   Age   Gender
 X      21     M
 Y      21     F
```

I need this type of result

```
Name|Age|Gender
X|21|M
Y|21|f
```

Including column names

Answer (score 15):

Press **Ctrl+T** to change to "Results from Text" (the button in SSMS is shown circled in red below):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are trying to change the result view in SQL Server Management Studio.

If this the case what you need is 'Result to Grid' option.

You need to go to:

Tools --> Options --> Query Results --> General --> and chnage Default Destination for results to 'Results to grids'

You can also use `Ctrl + D` to change the view to grid and 'Ctrl + T' to change it back to text.

or if you want to get the result with the pipe operator in between try the below query.

```
select name +'|'+age+'|'+gender from table
```

Comment: Toggling using ctrl+d / ctrl+t works but strangely SSMS does not respond to changing the settings under [Tools > Options > Query Results > General]. I'm using SSMS v17.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
 select Convert(nvarchar(50),name)+'|'+Convert(nvarchar(50),age)+'|'+Convert(nvarchar(50),gender) as column from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
select(convert(nvarchar(50),Name)+'|'+convert(nvarchar(50),Age)+'|'+convert(nvarchar(50),Gender)) 
[Name|Age|Gender]  from [Table_Name]
```